# Rate of position updates from gmapping

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey folks,

I am using a 2D SLAM with Navigation stack and Gmapping. My odometry is not so accurate and once I start to move I slightly drift from the real position. The localization algorithm on gmapping compensates my error but the problem is that is a bit slow for my application. I receive a correction almost every 5 secs and I want to make it faster like amcl which does the same thing almost in real time (The problem with amcl is that it only works if you have a map and I want to do slam). I went through the parameters available on gmapping and couldn't find any thing related to the rate of updates that I am receiving from localization.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222206/rate-of-position-updates-from-gmapping/) by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the parameter "map_update_interval" [Gmapping wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping). This parameter corresponds to interval between map updates. Its default value is 5 sec.

---

Originally posted by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) with karma: 166 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0